# how to pass module data between tableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I trying to pass a variable from one tableViewController to an other but How can I do this with data collected from a module?

I want to pass a title, a description and a image but nothing is excepted i get a error message  "Use of unresolved identifier"

Can anyone find what I've done wrong?

[image]

```
import UIKit

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var product: Product?
    @IBOutlet weak var matchImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK - VC life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         matchImage.image = product?.image
         nameLabel.text = product?.title
         descriptionLabel.text = product?.description

         var matchTitle = product?.title

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var editVC: EditTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EditTableViewController
    editVC.editName = matchTitle;

}
}
```

Matches Controller Table View Controller

```
import UIKit

class MatchesControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}

lazy var productLines: [ProductLine] = {
    return ProductLine.productLines()
}()


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let productLine = productLines[section]
    return productLine.name
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return productLines.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let productLine = productLines[section]
    return productLine.products.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MatchesCells", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MatchesTableViewCells
    let productLine = productLines[indexPath.section]
    let product = productLine.products[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCellWith(product)

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Edit Tableview
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
        let productLine = productLines[indexPath.section]
        productLine.products.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        // tell the tableview
       tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let identifier = segue.identifier{
        switch identifier {
            case "detail view":
                let detailTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTableViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell){
                    detailTableVC.product = productAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            }

            default: break
        }
    }
}

func productAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Product
{
    let productLine = productLines[indexPath.section]
    return productLine.products[indexPath.row]
}


}
```

the cells in the table MatchesTableViewCells

```
import UIKit

class MatchesTableViewCells: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!

func configureCellWith(product: Product)
{
    productImageView.image = product.image
    productDescriptionLabel.text = product.description
    productTitleLabel.text = product.title
}
```

}

EditTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class EditTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//Module:
var editName: String = ""
var editDescription: String = ""


@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var matchDescriptionTextArea: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var matchImage: UIImageView!


//MARK - VC life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //matchImage.image = editImg
    nameLabel.text = editName
    matchDescriptionTextArea.text = editDescription


}
}
```

Comment: If i try to put editVC.editName = nameLabel I get the error message "cannot assign a value of type 'UILabel!' to a value of string"

Comment: matchTitle is declared local to viewDidLoad() not a member variable of your class. Also you are not setting Product to anything.

Comment: so were should I declare it?

Comment: Same as where you are already declaring member variables

Comment: But then the product is not defined, the product is set when a other segue has run

Comment: nameLabel is a UILabel. editVC.editName is obviously not, you must have declared it as a string. Either declare it as a UILable, or get the string out of UILabel. Read the compiler error, it is telling you exactly and unambiguously what the problem is.

Comment: You haven't posted all your code, but it sounds like it may wrong on a high level. Or at the least more context is needed

Answer (score 0):

Your `matchTitle` was create in `viewdidload` load and it is not in context anymore in `prepareForSegue`

```
import UIKit

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var product: Product?

    @IBOutlet weak var matchImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK - VC life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         matchImage.image = product?.image
         nameLabel.text = product?.title
         descriptionLabel.text = product?.description  
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var editVC: EditTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EditTableViewController
    editVC.editName = product?.title;
    //Assuming editName is a string, if it is a UILabel it should be
    //editVC.editName.text = product?.title;
    //If editName is a string and product?.title a UITextField
    //editVC.editName = product?.title.text;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I get an error  cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'UITextField!'

Comment: or this - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: did you try as I add in the comment? "this editVC.editName.text = product?.title" it seems that you editName is not a String but an UITextField

Comment: yes, but I get the error - 'String' does not have a member named 'text'

Comment: I think the problem is that the product?.title is not specified until the viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you post your class EditTableViewController? Otherwise it is hard to know exactly what is heppening

Comment: You need to show your class Product and EditTableViewController I have no idea what is "other class"? Anyway I think your title var in Product class is a UITextField in that case "hard to say without see" I edit the post for that case

Comment: Thank for your time, Ive posted everything

Comment: i get the error- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Where is your class Product? How does the values get populate in products?

Comment: the values are populated through a module and the data are hardcoded in, the data is presented correctly in the detail view, but I want the data to be the same in editView. So what product is picked presented in the detail view and an edit button lead you in to the edit view were you should be able to edit that product that you picked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78257/discussion-between-icaronz-and-josef).